# Should I request the backend for every small piece of dynamic data?

Tags: angularjs

Let's suppose there's a page implemented with AngularJS.
Ideally the frontend (Angular app) and backend (Web services/API/ call it whatever you like) should be 100% separated from each other which means that frontend project doesn't have access to database at all. And that's what I want to achieve.

Let's say we're rendering product list. The workflow is:

- request and render HTML template (including JS code)
- Angular app runs
- Angular loads dynamic data (products data to show the list) and put it into the template.

We've made 2 requests so far (excluding js/css/images etc.) which is fine. Simple, effective, just great.
And that's what more or less is shown in tutorials/guides.  But that's not the reality. What I'm wondering is what about small pieces of data that are rendered across whole app layout but have to be retrieved from database.

Exmaples of such data are:

- usename of logged in user in top right corner
- menu with categories on the side bar
- even `<select>` options in forms are often loaded from database (categories again for example)

For me it doesn't make sense to make a request to backend for each of these pieces of data because it makes a lot of http requests to make on every page refresh/init

How to deal with it?

Comment: You need to get some metrics to prove you have a real problem or else you are doing premature optimization.

Comment: It's a question about theory "how it should be designed". There's no implementation to make any metrics on yet.

Answer (score 2):

At a super-high level, there's exactly two ways to mitigate this problem:

1) **Allow "batch" server requests**, so you can get all these random bits of data in one round-trip. This seems appropriate for all the little lists of categories you need to put in side bars and form fields.

2) **Cache information on the client** so you don't have to re-request it for every page. In particular, the username could easily be part of whatever session id/token/cookie/thingy you use to keep the user "logged in", and categories for the side bar are probably going to be the same on most pages.

As James said, there is some risk of premature optimization, but reducing the total number of server hops is almost always a performance win (when the server isn't doing anything besides fetching bits of pre-computed data for you).

Comment: First solution looks a bit hacky, the second is just caching which is an optimization thing, not the element of main dataflow. My question in a brief is "Is Angular really designed to make request for each data piece?". It's also just about the theory of software designing, so that's not a premature optimization since no code has been written yet. ;-)

Comment: @dragoste I don't think it's an Angular thing, it's a matter of whether the clientside code knows this stuff in advance or it simply needs to ask the server. And that's generally dictated by your business requirements. The only "design" involved is figuring out what those server requests look like (which can reduce the need for batching, admittedly).

Comment: @dragoste: Actually, chunking data requests in this manner is a best practice.  This is one of the purposes of ViewModel objects.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yea, that sounds great, but I've never seen such approach in action. Have you?

Comment: @dragoste A simple example we use frequently at my job: When the server request is "get human-readable name/description of this item", we teach the service to accept a list of item ids instead of just one, so we only have 1 server hop instead of N. This works very well "in action".